# FsCheck in C#: generate a list of two dimension arrays with the same shape

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fscheck, generative-testing

Let's say I'm writing some code for video analysis. Here is a simplified version of a Video class:

```
public class Video
{
    public readonly int Width;
    public readonly int Height;
    public readonly List<int[,]> Frames;

    public Video(int width, int height, IEnumerable<int[,]> frames)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Frames = new List<int[,]>();
        foreach (var frame in frames)
        {
            if (frame.GetLength(0) != height || frame.GetLength(1) != width)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect frames dimensions");
            }
            Frames.Add(frame);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make an `Arbitrary<Video>` and register it? How do I make a shrinker for that Arbitrary?

Tried this, couldn't understand how apply works:

```
public static Arbitrary<Video> Videos()
{
    var videoGen = Arb.Generate<PositiveInt>()
        .SelectMany(w => Arb.Generate<PositiveInt>(), (w, h) => new {w, h})
        .Apply( /* what is Gen<Func<a,b>> */);

    return videoGen.ToArbitrary();
}
```

Tried this, but couldn't plug the generator for list in here:

```
public static Arbitrary<Video> Videos()
{
    var videoGen = Arb.Generate<PositiveInt>()
        .SelectMany(w => Arb.Generate<PositiveInt>(), (w, h) => new Video(w, h, /* how to plug generator here? */));

    return videoGen.ToArbitrary();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Kurt Schelfthout's answer as a foundation, you can write an Arbitrary for the `video` class like this:

```
public static class VideoArbitrary
{
    public static Arbitrary<Video> Videos()
    {
        var genVideo = from w in Arb.Generate<PositiveInt>()
                       from h in Arb.Generate<PositiveInt>()
                       from arrs in Gen.ListOf(
                           Gen.Array2DOf<int>(
                               h.Item,
                               w.Item,
                               Arb.Generate<int>()))
                       select new Video(w.Item, h.Item, arrs);
        return genVideo.ToArbitrary();
    }
}
```

You can use this in various ways.

## Plain vanilla FsCheck

Here's how to use the Video Arbitrary with plain vanilla FsCheck, here hosted within an xUnit.net test case, which isn't required: you can host this in whichever process you prefer:

```
[Fact]
public void VideoProperty()
{
    var property = Prop.ForAll(
        VideoArbitrary.Videos(),
        video =>
        {
            // Test goes here...
            Assert.NotNull(video);
        });
    property.QuickCheckThrowOnFailure();
}
```

`Prop.ForAll` is very useful for defining properties with custom Arbitraries. When you call `QuickCheckThrowOnFailure`, it's going to run the test for 'all' (by defailt: 100) values of the `Video` class.

## Untyped xUnit.net property

You can also use the FsCheck.Xunit Glue Library, but you have to pass the Arbitrary as a weakly typed value to the attribute:

```
[Property(Arbitrary = new[] { typeof(VideoArbitrary) })]
public void XunitPropertyWithWeaklyTypedArbitrary(Video video)
{
    // Test goes here...
    Assert.NotNull(video);
}
```

This is simple and easy to understand, but there's no static type checking involved when assigning that `Arbitrary` property, so I'm not too fond of this approach.

## Typed xUnit.net property

A better way to use FsCheck.Xunit with custom Arbitraries is to [combine it with Prop.ForAll](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/08/ad-hoc-arbitraries-with-fscheckxunit):

```
[Property]
public Property XUnitPropertyWithStronglyTypedArbitrary()
{
    return Prop.ForAll(
        VideoArbitrary.Videos(),
        video =>
        {
            // Test goes here...
            Assert.NotNull(video);
        });
}
```

Notice that the return type of this method is no longer `void`, but `Property`; the `[Property]` attribute understands this type and executes the test accordingly.

This third option is my preferred way of using custom Arbitraries from within xUnit.net, because it brings back compile-time checking.

Comment: I didn't know the typed xUnit.net property, that is a great option!

Answer (score 6):

Just a spur of the moment sketch - not compiled :)

```
var genVideo = from w in Arb.Generate<PositiveInt>()
               from h in Arb.Generate<PositiveInt>()
               from arrs in Gen.ListOf(Gen.Array2DOf(h, w, Arb.Generate<int>))
               select new Video(w, h, arrs);
```

Comment: That gave me a good start, but I had to wiggle it a bit before it'd compile :)